# Strings to send from one activity to the third activity

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and I want to send strings present in editText on the first activity to the 3rd activity's textview, where my second activity should not be affected.

Comment: try to use `sharedPreferences`

Comment: Use the @Boss solution.

Comment: Using SharedPreference just to pass values is not preferred, please use intent or use a Singleton class to share the values across the app.

Comment: like i want to get edit text entered string  from 1st activity into third activity  textview

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preference_name",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    preferences.edit().putString("key", "your value").commit();
```

And in third activity

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preference_name",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String value = preferences.getString("key", "");
```

Comment: Using SharedPreference just to pass values is not preferred, please use intent or use a Singleton class to share the values across the app.

Answer (score 0):

Encode all EditText values to json, then pass json to second activity and third activity or save it to SharePreference and read in third activity

Comment: im not using any database, just basic thing, taking input text in one activity and displaying same text in 3rd activity,  thanks in advance